# How to create a new array from another one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one array:

```
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'horse']
```

And second one:

```
const animalsWithNames = ['cat:mik', 'dog', 'horse:lucy']
```

And I need to create a function that gives me in a result a third array:

```
const result = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse']
```

So, as well I understad I have to map first array and check by function. If piece of string exist in first array's item it should be in the result one. Am I right?
Please about tips or proposal solutions.

My attempt:

```
const checkStr = str => animalsWithNames.forEach(el => {
        if (el.substring(0, str.length) === str) {
            return str
        }
    })

const result = animals.map(el => checkStr(el))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: What you understand is correct, can you show us an attempt at a solution?

Comment: I added my attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like the following way:

```js
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'horse'];
const animalsWithNames = ['cat:mik', 'dog', 'horse:lucy'];
const result = animals.filter(a => animalsWithNames.some(an => an.split(':')[0] == a));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @karolina-szlenk, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Array.reduce` with looping through first array and checking the nodes is present in second.

```js
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'horse'];
const animalsWithNames = ['cat:mik', 'dog', 'horse:lucy'];
const result = animals.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = animalsWithNames.find(item => item.indexOf(curr) > -1);
  if (node) {
    acc.push(curr)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The author wants to filter the first array by the contents of the second array, not just filter away values after the `:`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'horse']
const animalsWithNames = ['cat:mik', 'dog', 'horse:lucy']

const names = animalsWithNames.map(e => e.split(":")[0])
const result = names.filter(e => animals.includes(e))

console.log(result)
```